# What's the difference between the CakePHP Plugin folders?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to CakePHP, and am working on getting things set up. One issue I've come across is that the initial folder has an app folder, as seen [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html). I'm confused as to why there are two plugins folders. There's one on the parent directory indicated there, as well as one in the app/plugins directory. Which one am I supposed to install plugins in? What is the other one used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder `cakeroot/app/Plugins` is specific to your application living in `app`, while `cakeroot/plugins` applies to all possible applications in `cakeroot` (you can place multiple applications in different directories in the root folder).

Personally I stick with one app per folder structure, which lets me easily manage different Plugin or Cake version requirements for every app. Although it means more space, all these files don't take that much to be an issue. It is also impractical if not impossible to monitor these requirements with version control otherwise.

Comment: It's ROOT/plugins (note the lowercase p).